# What to do about a displaced saddle on an acoustic guitar?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, maintenance

The saddle on my bridge is bending forward, is that normal?

[image]

My G string used to be fine but now it is sounding weird. What do I do?

Comment: If it's sloping towards the hole in the body, the intonation is out. Sacken strings, make it uoright, make sure as you re-tune, it doesn't start sloping again.

Comment: I don't really know. I just found it so I don’t really know anything about it.

Comment: The light piece is leaning toward the sound hole. But i fixed it by loosening the strings like Tim said. Thanks for everything, everyone.

Comment: @ChallengedGecko -- I have edited your question to make it clearer, based on your comments. You can always click on `edit` under your post to make clarifications, and this is a good thing to do so that visitors to the site with the same question can more easily find your question and any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the saddle is sloping forward (the white part in the slot) a thicker saddle would fix it. It's not unusual for inexpensive guitars to come with saddles that are way too thin.

Pick up a saddle at a guitar shop that's thicker than you need and file it to fit the width of the slot in the bridge. A cheap saddle is only a few dollars.

Or you can take it to a luthier to have it done for more dollars, but it'll be done right.